Green's Formula for vector fields in the Navier Stokes Weak Formulation
I am currently studying the weak formulation of the Navier-Stokes equations and came across the following equation:
\begin{equation}
\int_{\Omega} \mathbf{v} \cdot \Delta \mathbf{u} \, dx = -\int_{\Omega} \nabla \mathbf{v} : \nabla \mathbf{u} \, dx + \int_{\partial \Omega} \mathbf{v} \cdot (\nabla \mathbf{u} \, \mathbf{n}) \, ds
\end{equation}
I understand that this equation is derived using Green's theorem and the divergence theorem. However, I am having trouble understanding the product rule used in this context.
Could someone please provide a step-by-step explanation of how this equation is derived in the context of the weak formulation of the Navier-Stokes equation. Any insights or resources for further reading would also be greatly appreciated. In all the books I have checked the detailed steps are always skipped.

The Green's formula for vector fields u = (u1, u2, u3) and v = (v1, v2, v3) can be derived from the scalar Green's formula as follows:

Apply the scalar Green's formula to each component of the vector fields:
$$-\int_{\Omega} \Delta u_i v_i \, d\Omega = \int_{\Omega} \nabla u_i \cdot \nabla v_i \, d\Omega - \int_{\partial \Omega} \frac{\partial u_i}{\partial n} v_i \, d\gamma$$

Sum over all components:
$$-\int_{\Omega} \Delta \mathbf{u} \cdot \mathbf{v} \, d\Omega = \sum_{i=1}^{3} \left( \int_{\Omega} \nabla u_i \cdot \nabla v_i \, d\Omega - \int_{\partial \Omega} \frac{\partial u_i}{\partial n} v_i \, d\gamma \right)$$

Write the sum of the gradients as a Frobenius product and the sum over the boundary term as a dot product:
$$-\int_{\Omega} \Delta \mathbf{u} \cdot \mathbf{v} \, d\Omega = \int_{\Omega} \nabla \mathbf{u} : \nabla \mathbf{v} \, d\Omega - \int_{\partial \Omega} \frac{\partial \mathbf{u}}{\partial n} \cdot \mathbf{v} \, d\gamma$$



I came up with this answer after thinking a little bit more on it
